# Error installing php-db in Debian 10 Buster

Tags: php, linux, debian

I have been tried install php-db in Debian 10 Buster, which is a dependency required by PandoraFMS Console (I'm installing it) but not working to me.

when I try to install I lack the dependency:

```
[...]
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pandorafms-console:
   pandorafms-console depends on php-db; however:
      Package php-db is not installed.
```

And if I try to install php-db manually:

```
# apt install php-db
[...]
Package php-db is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php-db' has no installation candidate
```

In packages.debian.org I can search the package and I found that:

```
Package php-db

   + jessie (oldoldstable) (php): PHP PEAR Database Abstraction Layer
     1.7.14-3: all
   + stretch (oldstable) (php): Database Abstraction Layer
     1.9.2-1: all
   + sid (unstable) (php): Database Abstraction Layer
     1.9.2-2: all
```

For more information, the content of /etc/apt/sources.list is (obviated comments):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
```

The directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ is empty.

What I can do?

Comment: You can use docker for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I downloaded the package from [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/php-db), previously installing the necessary dependencies (apt install php-common php-pear) and performing the installation manually:

```
dpkg -i php-db_1.9.2-1_all.deb
apt-mark hold php-db
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `php-db` has been removed from debian buster (10).

[Debian tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/php-db) : on 2018-03-21 , *testing* refer to debian Buster (debian 10).